# Can I drop the primary key without dropping the referenced foreign key?

Tags: database, oracle

I wanted to drop the primary key without dropping the referenced foreign key. But the foreign key is disabled.

Later I again want to create a primary key with the same name and enable the foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanted to drop the primary key without dropping the referenced foreign key

Can't be done. The presence of  a referencing foreign key - disabled or otherwise - prevents the dropping of a primary key.

Your options are:

1. disable the primary key instead; or
2. drop and subsequently re-create the foreign key as well.

Which option suits better will depend on your motivations for dropping the primary key in the first place.

Comment: `Can't be done. The presence of a referencing foreign key` 
But why SQL doesn't allow the PK to be changed to a different Column without FK being dropped first? @APC